How to call the LWC/ Aura Cmp in List View Buttons directly?
We are moving Salesforce Classic to Lightning. In that process  I have a Opportunity Object . In that Opp List View I have a "Reset", This is an OnClick JS button. Now for this button I created a LWC component. Now my question is how to add this button or Action to Lightning List View. Itried all approaches.
I created new button and used URL - in that I gave component name in below forms
/lightning/cmp/c__MyAuraComponent
/lightning/r/c__MyLWC
/lightning/n/Your_Aura_Component_Name
/lightning/n/Your_LWC_Component_Name
I tried creating VF pages also.. Anyting not working,
Can anyone please help on this.?
Getting errors like Getting Error as "Page doesn't exist -- Enter a valid URL and try again" or The Page does not exist like that.
How to call the LWC/ Aura Cmp in List View Buttons directly?

Check if this may help. - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V000077j5GQSAY

This is not working

This Salesforce idea confirms that it's currently not possible to link a list view button directly to an LWC. But two indirect approaches are possible. Firstly, this 'coding with the force' video shows how to pass ids from a list view button into a screen flow. But secondly, you can also do it with ListViewButton -> VisualForcePage -> Aura -> LWC by using the standard lightning out pattern. For this second approach, the challenge is injecting the ids into the LWC, but it can be done with what feels like a little bit of a cludge.
First define a SetController extension to set the page size to more that the standard set controller's value of 20:
public class cbpSetController {
      ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc;
    
      public cbpSetController(ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc) {
        this.ssc = ssc;
        this.ssc.setPageSize(1000);
      }
}

Then define the usual visualforce / lightning out arrangement referencing the set controller extension, but add a small javascript preamble to get the full set of records from the set controller and inject them into an ids variable that you pass to the LWC:
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="opps" extensions="cbpSetController">
  <apex:includeLightning />  

  <div id="LightningComponentid" />  
  <script>
    let str1 = "{!records}";
    let str2 = str1.substr(1, str1.length-2);
    let ids = str2.split(", ");

    $Lightning.use("c:cbpMapAura", function() {
       $Lightning.createComponent("c:cbpMap",
          {ids: ids},
          "LightningComponentid",
          function(cmp) {
       });
    });
  </script>
</apex:page>

Finally, dont forget to add a getter and setter for the ids parameter in your LWC JS file:
_ids;

@api set ids(ids) {
    if(ids){
        this._ids=ids;
    }
}
    
get ids(){
    return this._ids;
}

Dont worry about declaring the ids parameter in your LWC's js-meta.xml config file. Default config file works fine in this context.
Hope that helps
